# Event SRV error 2012 in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

Error Warning "Event SRV error 2012 in Windows Server 2008 R2" is being logged with increasing frequency.

NIC drivers were updated recently.  There are some drops in the switches.

This is the error:

SRV 2012

While transmitting or receiving data, the server encountered a network error. Occassional errors are expected, but large amounts of these indicate a possible error in your network configuration. The error status code is contained within the returned data (formatted as Words) and may point you towards the problem.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the whole error? Or at least a copy/paste?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, there will be no impact as this is just a warning.

It is caused due to a race between send and disconnect of TCP Sessions on the server. Simply spoken , if the Server is responding to a TCP Packet from a client or server and at the same time the client / server disconnects the session and send a TCP disconnect request then Microsoft logs this warning. This could happen when both the send and disconnect happen almost at the same second.

You can safely ignore the warnings.

By they way, I recommend the following proactive steps:

- Update Symantec Drivers (If you are
  using Symantec)
- Update HP Drivers, use the latest ProLiant Support Pack (If you are using
  HP)
- Update Broadcom Drivers (If you are
  using Broadcom)

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigating this recently, and I found it was caused by some WAN optimiser applicances - which make an SMB session still appear to be open after the remote end has closed it.

If you are using WAN optimiser appliances, or any kind of SMB/CIFS proxy, this is almost certainly what's causing it.